# How to rotate individual shapes in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have been scratching my head over the past week trying to understand rotating shapes in WebGL. I am drawing 3 shapes that gets called from their own functions. The basic structure of the functions is kinda like this:

```js
function drawShape(vertices) {

    var a = vertices.length / 2;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);


    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, a);
  }
```

Now I have render where each shape function gets called. Kinda like this:

```js
function render() {
    angleInRadians += 0.1;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
 
    drawShape1();
    drawShape2();
  
    matrix = mat.rotation(angleInRadians);  
    
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

    requestAnimFrame( render );

}
```

The rotation function being:

```js
rotation: function(angle) {
      var a = Math.cos(angle);
      var b = Math.sin(angle);
      return [
        a,-b, 0,
        b, a, 0,
        0, 0, 1,
      ];
    },
```

I have been trying to get only 1 shape to rotate out of the 3. I tried using the uniform3fv before the drawArrays in the function which draws the shape that I want to be rotated but all the shapes rotate with it. How do I get only one shape to rotate?

Comment: You might find [these articles useful](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, It's generally more common to upload vertex data at init time and use it at render time. The code you posted is uploading vertex data at render time. It would also be more common to look up attrib locations at init time instead of render time.

In other words you have this

```
function drawShape(vertices) {

    var a = vertices.length / 2;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);


    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, a);
  }
```

But it would be more common to do something like this

```
const attribs = {
  vPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition"),
};

const shape = createShape(vertices);

...

drawShape(attribs, shape);

function createShape(vertices) {
  const bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  return {
    bufferId,
    numVertices: vertices.length / 2,
  };
}

function drawShape(attribs, shape) {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, shape.bufferId);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(attribs.vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrib.vPosition);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, shape.numVertices);
}
```

or something along those lines.

You'd likely also look up uniforms at init time and pass in the uniforms and set them inside drawShape, or not. Mostly the point is calls to `gl.bufferData`, `gl.getUniformLocation` and `gl.getAttribLocation` generally happen at init time

Next up, you need to set the uniforms once **per shape**.

```
matrix = mat.rotation(angleInRadiansForShape1);  
gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);
drawShape1();

matrix = mat.rotation(angleInRadiansForShape2);  
gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);
drawShape2();
```

But you need to add in more than just rotation otherwise all the shapes will appear at the same place.

Rotation matrices rotate around the origin (0,0). If you want to rotate around some other point you to translate your vertices. you can do this by multiplying your rotation matrix with translation matrices.

It's hard to show how to do it because it requires a math library and the way to use a math library is different for each library.

[This article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) describes how to multiply matrices using a functions created in the article.

To move the rotation point you'd do this.

```
var matrix = m3.projection(gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight);    
matrix = m3.translate(matrix, whereToDrawX, whereToDrawY);
matrix = m3.rotate(matrix, angleToRotate);
matrix = m3.translate(matrix, offsetForRotationX, offsetForRotationY);
```

I generally read that bottom to top so it's

1. `m3.translate(matrix, offsetForRotationX, offsetForRotationY)` = translate the vertices so their origin is where we want to rotate. For example if we have a box going from 0 to 10 across and 0 to 20 down and we want to rotate at bottom right corner then we need to move the bottom right corner to 0,0 which means we need translate -10, -20 so that bottom right corner is at the origin.
2. `m3.rotate(matrix, angleToRotate)` = do the rotation
3. `m3.translate(matrix, whereToDrawX, whereToDrawY)` = translate it where we actually want it to be drawn.
4. `m3.projection(gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight)` = convert from pixels into clip space

Example:

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  // lookup uniforms
  var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

  // Create a buffer to put positions in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Put geometry data into buffer
  setGeometry(gl);

  const shapes = [
    { 
      translation: [50, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [0, 0], // top left corner of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [1, 0, 0, 1], // red
    },
    { 
      translation: [100, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [-50, -75], // center of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [0, 1, 0, 1], // green
    },
    { 
      translation: [150, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [0, -150], // bottom left corner of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [0, 0, 1, 1], // blue
    },
    { 
      translation: [200, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [-100, 0], // top right corner of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [1, 0, 1, 1],  // magenta
    },
  ];

  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds

    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // draw a single black line to make the pivot clearer
    gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
    gl.scissor(0, 75, 300, 1);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    for (const shape of shapes) {
      shape.angleInRadians = time;
      
      // set the color
      gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, shape.color);

      // Compute the matrices
      var matrix = m3.projection(gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight);
      matrix = m3.translate(matrix, shape.translation[0], shape.translation[1]);
      matrix = m3.scale(matrix, shape.scale[0], shape.scale[1]);
      matrix = m3.rotate(matrix, shape.angleInRadians);
      matrix = m3.translate(matrix, shape.rotationOffset[0], shape.rotationOffset[1]);

      // Set the matrix.
      gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

      // Draw the geometry.
      var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
      var offset = 0;
      var count = 18;  // 6 triangles in the 'F', 3 points per triangle
      gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  }
}

var m3 = {
  projection: function(width, height) {
    // Note: This matrix flips the Y axis so that 0 is at the top.
    return [
      2 / width, 0, 0,
      0, -2 / height, 0,
      -1, 1, 1
    ];
  },

  identity: function() {
    return [
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  translation: function(tx, ty) {
    return [
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      tx, ty, 1,
    ];
  },

  rotation: function(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);
    return [
      c,-s, 0,
      s, c, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  scaling: function(sx, sy) {
    return [
      sx, 0, 0,
      0, sy, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  multiply: function(a, b) {
    var a00 = a[0 * 3 + 0];
    var a01 = a[0 * 3 + 1];
    var a02 = a[0 * 3 + 2];
    var a10 = a[1 * 3 + 0];
    var a11 = a[1 * 3 + 1];
    var a12 = a[1 * 3 + 2];
    var a20 = a[2 * 3 + 0];
    var a21 = a[2 * 3 + 1];
    var a22 = a[2 * 3 + 2];
    var b00 = b[0 * 3 + 0];
    var b01 = b[0 * 3 + 1];
    var b02 = b[0 * 3 + 2];
    var b10 = b[1 * 3 + 0];
    var b11 = b[1 * 3 + 1];
    var b12 = b[1 * 3 + 2];
    var b20 = b[2 * 3 + 0];
    var b21 = b[2 * 3 + 1];
    var b22 = b[2 * 3 + 2];
    return [
      b00 * a00 + b01 * a10 + b02 * a20,
      b00 * a01 + b01 * a11 + b02 * a21,
      b00 * a02 + b01 * a12 + b02 * a22,
      b10 * a00 + b11 * a10 + b12 * a20,
      b10 * a01 + b11 * a11 + b12 * a21,
      b10 * a02 + b11 * a12 + b12 * a22,
      b20 * a00 + b21 * a10 + b22 * a20,
      b20 * a01 + b21 * a11 + b22 * a21,
      b20 * a02 + b21 * a12 + b22 * a22,
    ];
  },

  translate: function(m, tx, ty) {
    return m3.multiply(m, m3.translation(tx, ty));
  },

  rotate: function(m, angleInRadians) {
    return m3.multiply(m, m3.rotation(angleInRadians));
  },

  scale: function(m, sx, sy) {
    return m3.multiply(m, m3.scaling(sx, sy));
  },
};

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a letter 'F'.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array([
          // left column
          0, 0,
          30, 0,
          0, 150,
          0, 150,
          30, 0,
          30, 150,

          // top rung
          30, 0,
          100, 0,
          30, 30,
          30, 30,
          100, 0,
          100, 30,

          // middle rung
          30, 60,
          67, 60,
          30, 90,
          30, 90,
          67, 60,
          67, 90,
      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform mat3 u_matrix;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1)).xy, 0, 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

If you didn't want to move the center of rotation just remove the last step related to `rotationOffset`

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  // lookup uniforms
  var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

  // Create a buffer to put positions in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Put geometry data into buffer
  setGeometry(gl);

  const shapes = [
    { 
      translation: [50, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [0, 0], // top left corner of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [1, 0, 0, 1], // red
    },
    { 
      translation: [100, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [-50, -75], // center of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [0, 1, 0, 1], // green
    },
    { 
      translation: [150, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [0, -150], // bottom left corner of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [0, 0, 1, 1], // blue
    },
    { 
      translation: [200, 75],
      scale: [0.5, 0.5],
      rotationOffset: [-100, 0], // top right corner of F
      angleInRadians: 0,
      color: [1, 0, 1, 1],  // magenta
    },
  ];

  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds

    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // draw a single black line to make the pivot clearer
    gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
    gl.scissor(0, 75, 300, 1);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    for (const shape of shapes) {
      shape.angleInRadians = time;
      
      // set the color
      gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, shape.color);

      // Compute the matrices
      var matrix = m3.projection(gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight);
      matrix = m3.translate(matrix, shape.translation[0], shape.translation[1]);
      matrix = m3.scale(matrix, shape.scale[0], shape.scale[1]);
      matrix = m3.rotate(matrix, shape.angleInRadians);
      //matrix = m3.translate(matrix, shape.rotationOffset[0], shape.rotationOffset[1]);

      // Set the matrix.
      gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

      // Draw the geometry.
      var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
      var offset = 0;
      var count = 18;  // 6 triangles in the 'F', 3 points per triangle
      gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  }
}

var m3 = {
  projection: function(width, height) {
    // Note: This matrix flips the Y axis so that 0 is at the top.
    return [
      2 / width, 0, 0,
      0, -2 / height, 0,
      -1, 1, 1
    ];
  },

  identity: function() {
    return [
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  translation: function(tx, ty) {
    return [
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      tx, ty, 1,
    ];
  },

  rotation: function(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);
    return [
      c,-s, 0,
      s, c, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  scaling: function(sx, sy) {
    return [
      sx, 0, 0,
      0, sy, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
  },

  multiply: function(a, b) {
    var a00 = a[0 * 3 + 0];
    var a01 = a[0 * 3 + 1];
    var a02 = a[0 * 3 + 2];
    var a10 = a[1 * 3 + 0];
    var a11 = a[1 * 3 + 1];
    var a12 = a[1 * 3 + 2];
    var a20 = a[2 * 3 + 0];
    var a21 = a[2 * 3 + 1];
    var a22 = a[2 * 3 + 2];
    var b00 = b[0 * 3 + 0];
    var b01 = b[0 * 3 + 1];
    var b02 = b[0 * 3 + 2];
    var b10 = b[1 * 3 + 0];
    var b11 = b[1 * 3 + 1];
    var b12 = b[1 * 3 + 2];
    var b20 = b[2 * 3 + 0];
    var b21 = b[2 * 3 + 1];
    var b22 = b[2 * 3 + 2];
    return [
      b00 * a00 + b01 * a10 + b02 * a20,
      b00 * a01 + b01 * a11 + b02 * a21,
      b00 * a02 + b01 * a12 + b02 * a22,
      b10 * a00 + b11 * a10 + b12 * a20,
      b10 * a01 + b11 * a11 + b12 * a21,
      b10 * a02 + b11 * a12 + b12 * a22,
      b20 * a00 + b21 * a10 + b22 * a20,
      b20 * a01 + b21 * a11 + b22 * a21,
      b20 * a02 + b21 * a12 + b22 * a22,
    ];
  },

  translate: function(m, tx, ty) {
    return m3.multiply(m, m3.translation(tx, ty));
  },

  rotate: function(m, angleInRadians) {
    return m3.multiply(m, m3.rotation(angleInRadians));
  },

  scale: function(m, sx, sy) {
    return m3.multiply(m, m3.scaling(sx, sy));
  },
};

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a letter 'F'.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array([
          // left column
          0, 0,
          30, 0,
          0, 150,
          0, 150,
          30, 0,
          30, 150,

          // top rung
          30, 0,
          100, 0,
          30, 30,
          30, 30,
          100, 0,
          100, 30,

          // middle rung
          30, 60,
          67, 60,
          30, 90,
          30, 90,
          67, 60,
          67, 90,
      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform mat3 u_matrix;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1)).xy, 0, 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

you might also find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html) useful

Comment: I have a doubt about the code (I'm starting with webgl just now), I see that functions like rotate, translate, scaling, you have it done in JavaScript, doing the matrix multiplication in JS. Wouldn't it be better to move the code to GLSL? Apart from being simpler the multiplication without needing a helper, it would take more advantage of the GPU, isn't it? Or is there a reason to do it at JS? Thank you so much!

Comment: It's done in JS as it's more flexible. Otherwise you need different shaders for every different situation. It's also done in JS (or rather on the CPU) because the most standard way to do matrix multiplication for 3D is with a [scene graph](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html). Three.js, Unreal, Unity, Godot, pretty much every game engine and 2d or 3d engine in existence use a scene graph. The graph is walked and the matrices multiplied on the CPU (JS/C++/C#). They are generally sent to GPU only by special needs like projectionMat, viewMat, modelMat, normalMat.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a individual rotation matrix (model matrix) for each shape. Define a separate angle per shape:

e.g

```
var angleShape1 = 0.0; 
var angleShape2 = 0.0;
```

Calculate the rotation matrix far each shape and set the uniform variable, **before** drawing a shape:

```js
function render() {

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    matrix1 = mat.rotation(angleShape1);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix1);
    drawShape1();

    matrix2 = mat.rotation(angleShape2);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix2);
    drawShape2();

    angleShape1 += 0.1;
    angleShape2 += 0.2;

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

This causes that the shapes are rendered with different model transformations and individual orientations.

Comment: I understand the use of different uniforms but how can I rotate the shapes around their own axis rather than all of them rotating around the center of the canvas?

Comment: @AnyNOUS The center of the shape has to be (0, 0). The translation of the shape has not to be added to the vertex coordinates. Use a 4x4 matrix instead of the 3x3 matrix to perform a rotation and translation by the matrix. Read a good tutorial. e.g. [WebGL Fundamentals - WebGL 2D Matrices](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html)